# Azure pipeline artifact public URL

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

Currently, I am generating some artifacts in my Azure pipeline.

Artifact URL:
[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/resources/Containers/23274347/drop?itemPath=drop%2FAzureFunctions&%24format=zip&saveAbsolutePath=false](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/resources/Containers/23274347/drop?itemPath=drop%2FAzureFunctions&%24format=zip&saveAbsolutePath=false)

[image]

This URL is private, How can I generate a public URL?

Comment: You can't. If you made your project into a public project, then people would be able to see and access those artifacts, along with source code and everything else in your project. An alternative is to push your binaries to a public Azure Blob Storage account.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure pipeline artifact public URL

Just as Danile said, we could not achieve this at this moment.

That because the artifacts are belong to the project. If the project is private, then the artifacts of the project is also private and cannot be made public.

If you want to get the artifact public URL, you could download the artifacts and put it the public network folder, and share the folder.

Or you could just publish the artifact to the Network folder directly:

[image]

Or you using the [FTP upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops) task.